# Help with parameters, REST and listdata.svc

Tags: jquery, rest, listdata.svc

I'm calling listdata.svc a few times with different URL's depending in what is selected, I have some issues with the parameters/filters.

First URL:

```
var listUrl = siteUrl + "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Pages?$filter=ApprovalStatus eq '0'&top=2&orderby=Modified desc";
```

This one only get items that are approved but it ignores the top and orderby, what am I doing wrong here? I've tried with various combos of moving the parameters around ,use &$ etc.

Second URL:

```
var listUrl = siteUrl + "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Pages?$filter=substringof('" + keyword + "',Keywords)";
```

This one works but I can't get it to only get items with the keywords AND are published, ordered by Modified.

Third URL:

```
var listUrl = siteUrl + "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Pages?$filter=ApprovalStatus eq '0'&$skip=" + displayedItems + "&top=1";
```

This one get only approved items but ignores skip and top.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.\

Update:
Looks like:

```
$.getJSON(listUrl,
            function (data) {
                $.each(data.d.results,
                function (i, result) {
```

causes the error when I use &$top in the URL..

Edit2:
Ok so when I use top I have to do `$.each(data.d,` instead of `$.each(data.d.result,`

Comment: Most of your parameters are missing `$`: $orderby, $skip, $top

Comment: updated my post with another url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get information *order by* a parameter and *filtered* with a specify word you can do something like this:

```
http://contoso/sites/sharepointlist/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/InventoryLocations()
     ?$filter=startswith(Part/SKU,'sku')
     &$orderby=Part/SKU
     &$expand=Part
     &$select=BinNumber,Quantity,Title,Id,PartId,Part/SKU,Part/Title
```

this is an example that I got from MSDN and I used it for my purpose and it works.